# Vertical and horizontal resizing textbox (C++/CLI)

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, c++-cli

Me need to set up automatic positioning of TextBox in layout (with horizontal and central alignment and resizing).

Docking don't work well, because it don't centering widget at vertical.

Disabling all anchors also work very badly. Look at picture below.

[image]

Comment: Why you minus this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate every time the ratio between the original state of the form and the actual state of the form handling `Resize` event of it. This number can be multiplied to the coordinate ( see `location` ) of the `textBox`, thus everytime your form is resized, the location of the textbox will stay the same.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I thought about this idea, but I hoped, that there is a more nicer solution. For example, in Qt such solution is exist.